# Gamblers ruin and the mean time calculating

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

There's a gambler with initial money $k=100\$$. He plays till bankruptcy or till having $N=500\$$. In every game he wins $100\$$ with probability $p=\frac{1}{2}$, loses $100\$$ with probability $q=\frac{1}{4}$ or the game ends in tie with probability $r=\frac{1}{4}$.

(a) Calculate the probability of racking up 500\$,

(b) Calculate the mean time of the game.

I've seen exercises with gamblers ruin, with $p$ and $q=1-p$, but in my case there's also $r$. Does it change much, or do  I just "forget" about the r and calculate the ruin of the gambler? I'm obviously referring to "Unfair coin flipping" -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin. There is a formula, and then I just have to solve a differential equation.

According to (b) I have no idea how should I calculate the above.

Please help with both sub-points. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Notice that probability of winning = $\frac{\textrm{probability of winning}}{\textrm{probability of not tieing}}=\frac23$, and likewise, probability of losing is $\frac13$. This reduces your problem to a typical gambler's ruin problem.

Comment: A good, general, way to approach questions like this is to work with states.  Let $\psi_i$ be the probability of getting to $5$ given that you start with $i$, so the answer you want is $\psi_1$. Of course $\psi_0=0,\psi_5=1$.  For the other $i$ we have $\psi_i=\frac 12\times \psi_{i+1}+\frac 14\times \psi_{i-1}+\frac 14\times \psi_i$ and you can just solve that system.  A similar calculation works for the expected time.

Comment: For (b), the probability of a win or lose game is $\frac34$ and of a tied game $\frac14$, i.e. in the ratio $3:1$.  So if you can calculate the expected number of win or lose games, then the expected total games is $\frac43$ of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lulu has given you a method for the probabilities of reaching $500$ before reaching $0$: dividing the values by $100$ to give you labels, you want to find the solution to $$\psi_i=\tfrac 12 \psi_{i+1} +\tfrac 14 \psi_i +\tfrac 14 \psi_{i-1} \\ \text{ i.e. } 2\psi_{i+1} -3 \psi_i + \psi_{i-1}=0$$ with the boundary conditions $\psi_0=0$ and $\psi_5=1$.  In particular you are trying to find $\psi_{1}$.  As Rushabh Mehta says, you would get the same answer ignoring ties by starting with $\psi_i=\frac 23 \psi_{i+1} +\frac 13 \psi_{i-1}$

For the expected time, you do something similar but this times have $$\tau_i=1+\frac 12 \tau_{i+1} +\frac 14 \tau_i +\tfrac 14 \tau_{i-1} \\ \text{ i.e. } 4+2\tau_{i+1} -3 \tau_i + \tau_{i-1}=0$$ with the boundary conditions $\tau_0=0$ and $\tau_5=0$, and in particular you are trying to find $\tau_{1}$.  My comment was that if you ignore ties by changing this to $t_i=1+\frac 23 t_{i+1} +\frac 13 t_{i-1}$ then you would get $\tau_i = \frac43 t_i$

Comment: Shouldn't the initial value for (a) be $\phi_0=1$ and $\phi_N=0$, where $N=5$? Because the probability of gambler's ruin given that the player starts with $0$ money is $1$?
Also I don't understand your boundary conditions for (b).

Comment: @MacAbra $\psi_0$ is the probability of winning the match when you have $\$0$, which is $0$ since you are bankrupt.  $\psi_5$ is the probability of winning the match when you have $\$500$, which is $1$ since you have hit your target.   $\tau_0$ is the expected number of future rounds when you have $\$0$, which is $0$ since you are bankrupt.  $\tau_5$ is the expected number of future rounds when you have $\$500$, which is $0$ since you have hit your target.

Comment: Henry, thank you for the complete explanation. Now I'm sure that I understand the initial values. 
But I have one more question. What if gambler wins $200\$$ instead of $100\$$ with the same probability and loses $100\$$ with given probability? Obviously there's a chance for a tie too (just like in my exercise).

Comment: @MacAbra - If the gambler wins $200$ instead of $100$, then you get terms like $\psi_{i+2}$ and also the possibility of reaching $\psi_6$